# Does it make sense to have Serverless Deployments for a Serverful Application?

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, serverless, vercel

I have an express application running on Google Compute Engine (serverful) with an Nginx Reverse proxy in front of it, and I want to use Vercel (serverless) for deployment previews. Does this make sense or would it be considered an anti-pattern?

Thank youuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't integrate Vercel with a Compute Engine. It's not necessarily an antipattern, it's just not possible with Vercel.

Take Knative, that comes on top of Kubernetes. You can deploy serverless application on top of serverful Kubernetes cluster.